# Intuition/reason behind method of rounding numbers with significant figures

Tags: error-analysis

**Edit**: Just found another answered question which is an exact copy of my question, check that if anyone has the same doubt.

[Why was this convention for Significant Figures set up?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/470879/why-was-this-convention-for-significant-figures-set-up?rq=1)

My teacher taught us the rules for rounding numbers with significant figures today, and they seem weird to me:

> All the usual rules of standard rounding off apply, except when the last digit is 5, then:
>
> 1. We add 1 to the second last digit if it's odd.

> 2. We don't change the second last digit if it's even.

> 3. In both cases, we make the last digit 0.

eg. $1.3765$ when rounded to 5 significant figures becomes $1.3760$, because 6 is even (if we are asked to round to only 4 significant figures, we remove the 0 at the end and simply write $1.376$).

Similarly, $1.3775$ rounded to 5 significant figures will become $1.3780$, and if rounded to 4 then it'll become $1.378$. In case of second last digit being odd, the process is the same as how I've been taught to round off numbers since childhood. Why do we not add 1 to the second last digit when it's even?

Is there a specific reason for this? Being used to normal rounding, this confuses me. My teacher says it is just a convention but I was just wondering if there is any logic to the convention being this way.

Comment: Please, notice that 1.3765 already has 5 significant figures. If rounded to 4 significant figures, it becomes 1.376.

Comment: @GiorgioP That's exactly what I've written

Comment: Not really. You wrote 1.3760. But that is not a 5-digit accurate approximation. It is neither a 4 digit approx since it contains a 5-th figure (the final 0).

Comment: Sorry if I'm missing something, but I've written "if we are asked to round to only 4 significant figures, we remove the 0 at the end and simply write 1.376". Are you saying rounding it to 5 figures does *not* give 1.3760?

Comment: Absolutely not. Rounding to the nearest floating-point number with X significant decimal figure means that the uncertainty on the rounded value is within 0.5 times the value of the X-th figure. If your number starts with 5 significant figures, say 1.3765, the 4-significant figure rounding is 1.376. There is no rounding to 5 significant figures because the number has already 5 significant figures. You have to keep all.

Comment: More on [significant figures](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+significant+figures).

Answer (score 1):

I've never heard of this system. It might be because, if the last digit is 5, it's "equally able to round itself up or down". Then you assign half of the numbers (either odd or even) the "up" rounding and the other half the "down" rounding, to represent this.